# QEMU / virt-manager - Changing a hypervisor desktop while inside virtual machine

Tags: qemu, virt-manager

I am running openbox desktop on my physical machine where I navigate desktops using key combinations <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> or <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>...

My physical machine has a QEMU hypervisor installed and there is a virtual machine (VM) running on the hypervisor.

I mostly run VM in fullscreen mode where key combinations for desktop navigation do not work. How can I override the VM so that my key combinations will apply to the physical machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using VMM (virt-manager), by pressing grab keys you should be able to send keyboard inputs to the host OS desktop.

The grab key defined in `edit->preferences->console`

[image]

Comment: It seems to work! I defined a *"Grab keys"* combination as: META + ESC. Now when I am inside a VM *(fullscreen)* I only press META + ESC once to first escape the VM and then whatever I press next will directly execute inside my workstation and  not inside VM - for example META + 1 will bring me to workspace's *"desktop 1"*. Awesome!